# Derivates and Limits in the Same Problem are an Issue.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, limits, derivatives

I am working on the following problem:-

Evaluate $$\lim_{ x→1} \frac{x^{\frac{1}{4}} - 1}{x^{\frac{1}{3}} - 1}$$
    by relating it to the derivatives of functions.

Now this is quite a confusing problem as I am not able to know what the latter part of the question means. I can just find the limit which results $\frac{3}{4}$ but i still fail to answer how it relates to the derivates of functions.

Comment: Try writing this as $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^{1/4}-1}{x-1}\cdot\frac{x-1}{x^{1/3}-1}$ first.

Comment: Please elaborate as I do not understand. Thanks.

Comment: Now rewrite the second factor as $\frac{1}{\frac{x^{1/3}-1}{x-1}}$, and then interpret the limits of the two factors as $x\rightarrow1$ as derivatives.

Comment: Can you plz add an answer. Its confusing.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of a differentiable function $f$ at $x=a$ can be defined as:
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$
Re-write your limit as:
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{x^{1/4}-1}{x-1} \frac{x-1}{x^{1/3}-1}$$
At $x=1$, the derivative of $x^{1/4}$ is $\frac{1}{4}$ and the derivative of $x^{1/3}$ is $\frac{1}{3}$.  When $\lim f$ and $\lim g$ are finite and non-zero, we can write $\lim (f/g) = (\lim f) / (\lim g)$.  So here we can write the limit as:
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{x^{1/4}-1}{x-1} / \lim_{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{x^{1/3}-1}{x-1}$$
And the result is $\frac{3}{4}$.